# multiprocessing share object (socket) between process.

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, pyqt5, python-3.6

I would like to create a Process that store many objects(connect to devices via socket).

I have a GUI (PyQT5) that should store information about progress abut processes and status about devices. Example tell more:

```
# Process1
def conf1():
  dev = some_signal_that_ask_about_dev("device1");
  conf_dev(dev)
  return_device("device1", dev)


# Process2
def conf2():
  dev = some_signal_that_ask_about_dev("device2");
  do_sth_withd_dev(dev)
  return_device("device2", dev)


# Process3
class DevicesHolder(object):

    self.devices = {
        "device1": Device1("192.168.1.1", 8080),
        "device2": Device2("192.168.1.2", 8081)
      }

    def some_signal_that_ask_about_dev(self, dev_name):
        if self.devices[dev_name]:
            dev = self.devices[dev_name]

            # this device is taken by process.
            # If process take device and faild. device should be recreated!
            self.devices[dev_name] = None 
            return dev

    def return_device(dev_name, dev):
        self.devices[dev_name] = dev

    def get_status_of_devices():
        # Check connection to devices and return response
        pass 


# Process 4:
# GUI:
get_status_of_device();
```

So `process1` and `process2` do some work and sending progress to GUI. I would like to have info about devices status also.

> Why just not create local object (process) and sending info from that process?

Process can run for a few seconds. When apps run for minutes. I want to know that there is connection problem before I press a start button. And all apps fail because of connection.

**I think I am complicating simple problem. Help me!**

**More info**
Every process is configuring sth else but on the same connection.
I would like to work this as quick as possible.
It will work on Linux. But I care about multi platform.

Comment: So what exactly are you asking? As it stands, your question seems very broad and ill-defined.

Comment: How to share device object between process? On the other hand the way how should I do this proper. Sharing object between process in my opinion is terrible solution.

Comment: Your intuition is correct. What you are looking for is called [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). Probably a local socket will provide the simplest solution. The Qt docs have an [example of this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-ipc.html), and you can find a pyqt version of it [here](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/tree/master/examples/ipc). If you need to send/receive complex data, use [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?module-json).

Comment: The example is nice. But showing a trivial example of sharing text data. I have a real device. Like printer or phone. Sb can cut a wire or plug off device. My process configure this 'printer' each separately. I want access to this `socket` (my object store information how to talk throught this socket) from two process. This probably bad designed.. I should probaly create this object in each process. I don't know.

Comment: I gave a simple. generic example, because your question is so broad and ill-defined.